# Better name for what is usually called "random variable"?

Tags: probability, terminology

A "random variable" isn't a variable. It is a function. It isn't even "random".

A random variable is a surjective function from a sample space $S$ to a set of values $V$, where $V$ is measurable.

Have there been discussions regarding more transparent labels for the functions usually referred to as "random variable"s?

Comment: I think there is a big disconnect between how pure mathematicians conceptualize random variables and how most practitioners conceptualize random variables. When you're outside of the axiomatic weeds of probability theory and you're doing, say, data science, the fact that random variables are functions on some sample space is obscured--and you really don't care about the underlying probability space, just the distributions of the random variables and their relative independence from each other. So I'm not sure the entire community using probability would all feel the need for a new term.

Comment: What do "better" and "more transparent" mean?  Eepperly16's comment is well taken: better for pure mathematicians or better for practitioners? What's transparent to the one group is probably opaque to the other.

Comment: @eepperly16 Sure, and I do not care about the opinions of those who do not feel that there is a need for a better term. Not because I do not value their opinions, but because their opinions are not relevant (since as you mentioned, they do not find a need) to the question I am asking, and the outcome of the discussion generated by this question would not affect them. I am simply interested in the opinions of those who did feel there was a need for a better term. I hope that clarifies?

Comment: @kimchilover Whoever cares for using definitions that work properly with axiomatic probability? I dislike the dichotomy between "pure mathematicians" and "practitioners" that your comment implicitly assumes, so I don't think that such discussion would only be relevant to one particular group?

Comment: @eepperly16 I meant surjective and have corrected that in the post.

Comment: *"[...] to a set of real values $V$"* Really?

Comment: @ClementC. I will be happy to rewrite it as you suggest?

Comment: A r.v. can take values in any measurable space.

Comment: @ClementC. Not every author adopts this convention. Kallenberg for example, defines a measurable function from a probability space to any measurable space to be a _random element_ reserving the term _random variable_ for real-valued measurable functions

Comment: @eepperly16 So now we have to discuss *two* new names?

Comment: Probabilistic Variables makes more sense.

Answer (score 1):

If the term random variables is undesirable, then I would propose you simply called them measurable functions. This is, indeed, what random variables are in abstract probability theory and it does characterize their two important properties: that they are functions on the sample space and that the preimage of every measurable set in $\Bbb R$ is measurable (**EDIT**: or some other measurable space, if you prefer--see below)

Comment: Why does that function need to take value in $\mathbb{R}$? Before changing the name, maybe using the actual definition would help.

Comment: @ClementC. Different people use definitions. I've definitely had analysis professors call a measurable function $f : (\Omega, \mathcal{A}, \Bbb P) \to (\Bbb R, \mathcal{B}(\Bbb R), m)$ to be "measurable" rather than "$\mathcal{A}-\mathcal{B}(\Bbb R)$ measurable". The term "random variable" is also somewhat ambiguous: some authors require the codomain to be $\Bbb R$, $\Bbb R$ or $\Bbb C$, or any $\Bbb R^n$ for $n \ge 1$. So I don't think referring to random variables as measurable functions is inherently more ambiguous to referring to them as random variables: in all cases, context matters

Comment: Setting aside the fact that some definitions may specify real values (I would say that's a bad teaching choice. If you start dealing with all that abstract stuff, might as well give the general definition and then specialize it, rather than the other way around), I don't quite get your last sentence. I never said "measurable functions" was more ambiguous, and more to the point, "measurable functions" does not imply real-valued either at all.

Comment: 1/ @ClementC. I guess I'm not sure what your objection is to calling random variables measurable functions, then. Whatever definition you use, I'm sure all parties would agree random variables are precisely measurable functions whose domain is a probability space. As shown in my first comment to the OP, I find the term random variable to be satisfactory already and didn't feel the need for a new term. But if the OP feels random variable is a bad term

Comment: 2/ (which I have seen non-math majors in probability classes very confused on this point so it is understandable why the OP feels this way),  then  it is my opinion that measurable function is probably the best substitute term that already exists in the literature. (I personally agree with you that random variables should be described with an abstract codomain. Many authors (and virtually all in undergrad textbooks) do not adopt this convention, however, so I think it is unfair to say there's a consensus that random variables have arbitrary measurable spaces as codomains)

Comment: I only objected to your use of $\mathbb{R}$ at the end. (I don't have any other beef with your answer, which, after the edit, I upvoted.)

Comment: @eepperly16 FYI: I am a math major, but not sure how that factors into a request for whether discussion has occurred regarding better terms for "random variable". Regardless, I have chosen to downvote your answer for two reasons: 1) measurable functions are a more general class of functions than random variables: while it is true that all random variables are measurable functions, and that any measurable function could be a random variable over an appropriately defined set of outcomes + probability distribution over that set, conceptually random variables are something more than that. [cont.]

Comment: @eepperly16 2) I asked for references to discussion regarding alternate terms, which you did not provide; note that the first submitted version of my post down to the current version all state: "Have there been discussions regarding more transparent labels for the functions usually referred to as "random variable"s?". Since your response does not reference discussion by mathematicians, I do not believe your response is an answer.

Comment: @user89 Every measurable function comes with a specified measurable target space hence every measurable function is a random variable. The probability measure only comes into play when one needs to know the distribution of the random variable, not to decide if a given function is a random variable or not. Another strange feature of your worldview on these matters is your insistence on the target space being the image set of the function. Not so.

Comment: @Did The "strange features" of my "worldview" are simply "misunderstandings" of "something I am still trying to understand", and nothing more nefarious.

Comment: Unless I missed something, nobody mentioned nefariousness here. A kind of insularity, on the other hand, is rather striking.